# Processing abandoned The video could not be processed

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, video-upload

I followed this link with the second answer (two steps) to implement the video upload to Youtube: [Upload video on Youtube using curl and api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274173/upload-video-on-youtube-using-curl-and-api-v3)

The code works fine, but when I executed, I got response saying: 
status:
embeddable: true
license: "youtube"
privacyStatus: "unlisted"
publicStatsViewable: true
uploadStatus: "uploaded"

That means it is working, but when I went to my youtube account to check the video on videos list, it said:
Processing abandoned
The video could not be processed

The video is not playable with a red triangle, so are there any more info about why? and how to fix it? the video is about 30 seconds long, and when I manually upload from my youtube account UI, it works.
also my scope is configured with:
scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-channel-audit',
                 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload']

Answer (score 1):

Export your video again and save it in a different format supported by Youtube. at first, youtube kept abandoning the processing of my mp4 video but when I saved it as MOV, I was able to upload it with ease. Hope it helps because uploading with video classic didn't fix my issue.

Comment: I got the same error while uploading the videos as MOV. However, it worked for me by uploading it as MP4.

Answer (score 0):

This video will explain to you all the possible reasons for your video rejection by youtube. 
watch till the end so you can understand what is wrong with your video.

https://youtu.be/-iVtTHhfYtA
This is a new video with new reasons behind youtube rejection

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Electron. Solved by moving the API call from rendering process to main process. Apparently the video didn't upload at all using the node.js API in browser context.

Comment: Thanks a million! Couldn’t have pulled this off without your comment.